# An Elementary Solution to a Polynomial Problem?

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials

The following problem is from Larson's problem solving through problems:

> If $a,b$ and $c$ are the roots of the equation $x^3-x^2-x-1=0$, show that
>   $$
>   \frac{a^{1000}-b^{1000}}{a-b}+
>   \frac{b^{1000}-c^{1000}}{b-c}+
>   \frac{c^{1000}-a^{1000}}{c-a}
> $$
>   is an integer.

My way is to observe that $$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^{1000}-y^{1000}}{x-y}+\frac{y^{1000}-z^{1000}}{y-z}+\frac{z^{1000}-x^{1000}}{z-x}$$
is a symmetric polynomial and hence the result follows immediately from the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials together with Viete's theorem.

But I would like to ask if there is a more elementary solution to this problem because of the origin of this problem, thanks!!

Comment: It is easy to see $f_k = \frac{a^k-b^k}{a-b} + \frac{b^k-c^k}{b-c} + \frac{c^k-a^k}{c-a}$ satisfies $f_{k+3}-f_{k+2}-f_{k+1}-f_{k} = 0$ for $k \ge 0$. Since $f_0 = 0, f_1 = 3$ and $f_2 = 2(a+b+c) = 2$ are all integers, so does $f_k$ for all $k \ge 0$.

Comment: @achillehui +1 for your answer